# Twillio Text Response won't repsond

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, twilio

The code is below. It runs on a aws ec2 server running Ubuntu. This is python code. When I text the number it respond in the console: - - [02/Apr/2016 15:27:56] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

but it never texts my device back. How can I fix this? Thanks.

```html
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import twilio.twiml
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient



app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug = False)

@app.route('/text/<text>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def text(text):
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""


    response = twiml.Response()
    response.message("Hello, Mobile Monkey")
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You should check your twilio config

Comment: Twilio is posting to `/` not `/text/<text>`, so as @daniil said, check your Twilio config to see where they are posting

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks as though your Twilio number is set to POST new messages to `/` but your route is set up to be `/text/<text>`.

You'll need to change a couple of things. Firstly, Twilio will not set URL parameters like `<text>`, so you can remove that from your route.

```
@app.route('/text', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def text(text):
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""


    response = twiml.Response()
    response.message("Hello, Mobile Monkey")
    return str(resp)
```

Then you'll want to change your [number configuration](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming) so that the messaging URL points at `/text`.

Check out this [quickstart guide for a bit more information on sending SMS messages in Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/hello-monkey).

Let me know if that helps at all.